# Static method in Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, data-access-layer

I have used a lot of static methods in Data Access Layer (DAL) like:

```
public static DataTable GetClientNames()
{
    return CommonDAL.GetDataTable("....");
}
```

But I found out that some developers don't like the idea of static method inside DAL. I just need some reason to use or not use static methods inside DAL.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From purists' point of view, this violates all kinds of best practices (like, dependency on implementation, tight coupling, opaque dependencies, etc.). I would've said this myself, but recently I tend to move towards simpler solutions without diving too much in "enterprizey" features and buzzwords. Therefore, if it's fine with you do write code like this, if this architecture allows for fast development and is testable and, most important, solves your business problem -- its's just fine.

Comment: I found the same issue again in another project. I think the static DAL is against OOP basic ideas and it is NOT scaled well. I also think that adding IOC container can avoid this kind of static DAL.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to pick one reason not to use static methods, that would be that it limits your ability to write unit tests against your code. For example creating mocks for your DAL will be more difficult because there is not an actual interface to code against, just a bunch of static methods. This further limits you if/when you decide to adopt frameworks that require interfaces to support things like IoC, dependency injection etc.

Comment: This is also very good point and I just found this issue today with IOC.

Answer (score 0):

That's `Unit of Work`, just static, isn't it?

Comment: We need to read clients names from DB and you can say it is static. But even instance calls end up with static calls by CLR. Not sure when to use static calls and when to use instance calls.

Comment: @Tony: What is your data source? ORM? Something else?

Comment: Data is saved in SQL server and binding used datatable. No ORM used.